# Get all entries and their relations, if present

Tags: mysql

I have the following mysql tables defined:
Group Tables:

[image: Group table scheme]

Hosts Tables:

[image: Host table scheme]

And the Groups <-> Hosts Relation Table:

[image: group to host relation scheme]

And I have the following SQL Query to get all groups (!) with their host relations:

```
SELECT host_groups.id, host_groups.groupname, host_groups.description, 
hosts.id AS hostid, hosts.hostname
FROM host_groups, hosts, relation_host_hostgroup
WHERE host_groups.id = relation_host_hostgroup.hostgroupid
AND hosts.id = relation_host_hostgroup.hostid;
```

And the output is:

[image: SQL Statement output]

So as you can see, the result is only returning the groups with an existing membership over the table `relation_host_hostgrou`p.

But my goal would be to get every group with or without their host relationship.

Is this possible?

Can I just say

```
if(group.id is in relation_host_hostgroup table){
 print(hostid, hostname)
}
else{
 print(hostid=none, hostname=none)
}
```

Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need outer joins to get all groups:

```
SELECT g.id, 
       g.groupname, 
       g.description, 
       h.id AS hostid,
       h.hostname
FROM host_groups g
     LEFT JOIN relation_host_hostgroup rh ON g.id = rh.hostgroupid
     LEFT JOIN hosts h ON rh.hostid = h.id;
```

Now, if there's no matching entry in relation_host_hostgroup or hosts, then h.id and h.hostname will be `NULL`. Of course, you can e.g. use COALESCE to replace `NULL` with some other value.